# Retrieve data for each partition based on a date range from other column in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There's a DataFrame in PySpark with data as below:

**Original data:**

```
Shop Customer date        retrive_days
A    C1       15/06/2019  2
A    C1       16/06/2019  0
A    C1       17/06/2019  0
A    C1       18/06/2019  0
B    C2       20/07/2019  5
B    C2       21/07/2019  0
B    C2       23/07/2019  0
B    C2       30/07/2019  0
B    C2       01/08/2019  6
B    C2       02/08/2019  0
B    C2       03/08/2019  0
B    C2       09/08/2019  0
B    C2       10/08/2019  1
B    C2       11/08/2019  0
B    C2       13/08/2019  0
```

Each customer has a date he/she visited the shop and each customer also has retrive_days and that many days data has to be fetched to the output.

I am trying to get an output which should look like this in PySpark, filtered based on the retrive_days value for each customer

**Expected Output:**

```
Shop Customer date        retrive_days
A    C1       15/06/2019  2
A    C1       16/06/2019  0
B    C2       20/07/2019  5
B    C2       21/07/2019  0
B    C2       23/07/2019  0
B    C2       01/08/2019  6
B    C2       02/08/2019  0
B    C2       03/08/2019  0
B    C2       10/08/2019  1
B    C2       11/08/2019  0
```

Comment: can you post what you tried and what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: what do you mean by retrieve days ? the question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this with **`window functions`**.

*In your example output, the last row should be omitted because for your other 2,5,6 logic the date should not equal the max date( retrive_days + date ). If thats not the case do* `filter('date1<=max_date')` .

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w1=Window().partitionBy("Shop","Customer").orderBy("date1")
w2=Window().partitionBy("Shop","Customer","partitions")

df.withColumn("date1", F.to_date("date", "dd/MM/yyyy"))\
  .withColumn("partitions", F.sum(F.expr("""IF(retrive_days!=0, 1, 0)""")).over(w1))\
  .withColumn("max_date", F.max(F.expr("""IF(retrive_days!=0,date_add(date1,retrive_days),null)""")).over(w2))\
  .filter('date1<max_date').drop("date1","max_date","partitions").show()

#+----+--------+----------+------------+
#|Shop|Customer|      date|retrive_days|
#+----+--------+----------+------------+
#|   A|      C1|15/06/2019|           2|
#|   A|      C1|16/06/2019|           0|
#|   B|      C2|20/07/2019|           5|
#|   B|      C2|21/07/2019|           0|
#|   B|      C2|23/07/2019|           0|
#|   B|      C2|01/08/2019|           6|
#|   B|      C2|02/08/2019|           0|
#|   B|      C2|03/08/2019|           0|
#|   B|      C2|10/08/2019|           1|
#+----+--------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Murtihash it works if the customer has only one visit for a shop but in reality, there are N number of visits by each customer to the same or different shop with the same or different retrieve_days.